# oracle pl sql how to Remove duplicate emails from a string

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am looking for something in oracle 10R2 to eliminate the duplicates from a string which carries email addresses.

I/p to a string-

```
v_temp := abc@test.com,ert@test.com,xyz@test.com,def@test.com,ert@test.com,xyz@test.com
```

Required O/p

```
abc@test.com,ert@test.com,xyz@test.com,def@test.com
```

I am trying as below with regexp_replace but not coming desired output.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
v_temp varchar2(5000) := 'abc@test.com,ert@test.com,xyz@test.com,def@test.com,ert@test.com,xyz@test.com';
l_temp varchar2(5000);
begin
l_temp := regexp_replace( v_temp ,'([^,]+)(,[ ]*\1)+');
dbms_output.put_line(l_temp);
end;
/
```

Much appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: In PL/SQL: `DECLARE v_temp VARCHAR2(4000) := 'abc@test.com,ert@test.com,xyz@test.com,def@test.com,ert@test.com,xyz@test.com'; v_unique StringList; BEGIN v_unique := SET( split_string( v_temp ) ); /* Iterate over collection and concatenate as needed */ END;/` The type and function are declared in the answer to the linked question and there is also an example using regular expressions.

Comment: I have tried this but still duplicates are coming  ---- DECLARE
  v_temp VARCHAR2(4000) := 'abc@test.com,ert@test.com,xyz@test.com,def@test.com,ert@tes‌​t.com,xyz@test.com';
  v_unique StringList;
BEGIN
  v_unique := SET( split_string( v_temp ) );
  /* Iterate over collection and concatenate as needed */
  FOR i IN v_unique.FIRST .. v_unique.LAST LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(v_unique(i));
        END LOOP;
  
END;
/

Comment: Also tried the regexp from the link but could not mange to work that line of code --- REGEXP_SUBSTR( ',' || v_temp || ',', ',([^,]+),(.+,)?\1,', 1, 1, NULL, 1 );

Comment: Please check your string - copy pasting to an SQLFiddle there were some unprintable characters in the second duplicate.

Comment: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75956/2)

Comment: If you can help me with the "regexp" then that will great help because here it will not allow external functions to install in DB

Comment: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d6769/1) - PL/SQL with no functions.

Comment: easiest solution than the one suggested by MT0, it estimate
----
`declare
   type email_list is table of varchar2(50);
   l_email_list email_list;
begin
   l_email_list := email_list('abc@test.com', 'ert@test.com', 'xyz@test.com', 'def@test.com', 'ert@test.com', 'xyz@test.com');

   l_email_list := l_email_list multiset intersect distinct l_email_list;
   for i in 1 .. l_email_list.count loop
      dbms_output.put_line(l_email_list(i));
   end loop;
end;`

Comment: This post needs to be reopened so @SebG can post his solution for consideration as a proper answer..

Comment: @MT0 I am using oracle 10g so REGEXP_COUNT is not available :-( can we use any other function to count number of "," commas

Comment: @SebG - post it in the thread this is a duplicate of.

Comment: Not sure that is exactly an answer for other topic.

Comment: Added another answer to the question this is a duplicate of. No regular expressions or collections and you should just be able to take the body of the function and run it in your PL/SQL block to remove the duplicates.